# jQueryUI and tabs' json content rendering

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ui

I am perfectly capable of loading json returned data (which appears "as is" in my html page), however i do not seem to be able to make the raw json data disappear. I have used the following code:

```
$( "#tavole" ).tabs({
    cache : false,
    event: "mouseover",
    ajaxOptions : {
        cache : false,
        dataType : 'json'
    },
    beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
            ui.panel.html( "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " + "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
        });
    },
    load: function (event, ui ) {
        renderList(JSON.parse($(ui.panel).text()));
    }
});
```

the above code works fine and renderList gets executed, however the raw json return appears in the tab panel no matter what. How do i make it disappear so that i get only the processed jquery object rendered displayed?

this is my html:

```
<div id="tavole">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tavole-1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-locked"></span>alfa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tavole-2"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-person"></span>beta</a></li>
        <li><a href="/api/products"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-cart"></span>gamma</a></li>
```

so in other words I get the return of `/api/products` displayed once in the tab's panel and a second time through the renderList function.

How do I get to see only the rendered display? why am i also seeing the raw json return from `/api/products`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get to see only the rendered display? why am i also seeing
>   the raw json return from /api/products?

This is the idea behind the ajax initialized tabs, the widget will simply display the content returned by the ajax call.

You could either have the server render an actual HTML fragment, or have renderList return its result instead of interacting with the DOM itself, which would give you the chance to:

```
load: function (event, ui ) {
    var $panel = $(ui.panel)
    var myHtml = renderList(JSON.parse($panel.text()));
    $panel.html(myHtml);
}
```

Your best bet though would be to write a custom converter function for your ajax call. Right now, you're using the "json" converter for your ajax result, which defaults to `JSON.parse`.
Have a look at the documentation of [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.Ajax/), section `converters`. It should be possible to hook up a custom converter function to your ajax call in the tabs' `beforeLoad` event handler (see [tabs -> event: beforeLoad](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeLoad)), which will a) do the JSON parsing and b) calls your renderList function. This will make the `load` event of your `tabs` obsolete.

The latter version is certainly the most complicated one, but (while I haven't done it myself) I also find it to be the cleanest approach.

Comment: hi, tks for taking the time to answer :)

Comment: hi, tks for taking the time to answer :)

this is somewhat unexpected. i really thought that it should be much easier to do that...

Now, by using:

load: function (event, ui ) {
    var $panel = $(ui.panel)
    var myHtml = renderList(JSON.parse($panel.text()));
    $panel.html(myHtml);
}

I am still getting both the raw json and my json object well formatted... No idea how to get rid of the raw json. There should be a way.

My grasp is that $(ui.panel) is not actually addressing the raw data, but just the ajax object. which are basically two distinct entities.

Comment: sorry my last comment was a mess... still not too familiar with formatting.

maybe i should try the custom converter, however i fear that i will end up again like before: having two entities 1) the raw return and 2) the jquery object

Comment: `$(ui.panel)` will reference the DOM entity that is the container for your tab. The idea was to clear whatever is put in there by default. My suggestion will not work if `load` happens before the response is inserted. I must admit I haven't verified that, and the documentation is somewhat unclear on that particular issue.

Comment: UweB, actually my bad, i did not implement it correctly. now i fixed it and it's working as you suggested.